# InfoPath form sent to users automatically and Button to update SharePoint List 2010

Tags: infopath

I have been requested to create a form that will be submitted to users at 4 am every Monday. When the user receives the form via email, they user will make updates to the form (removing employees that are no longer employed), select a submit button and the form will update a SharePoint List. Was advised not to make the changes to the database.

So far I have created the form using the database option, the data queries what I want it to. However, when I create the submit button and set rules to update the SharePoint List, the list is not updated and it is as though the data disappears (probably because list is not an option, but library is).

When I set the button to send an email, I do receive the email, but this email is supposed to be sent to the user after changes were made to the form (which happens), so they should be receiving a 'read only' form, but that is not the case. This email is not as important as first knowing if I can use an InfoPath form to update a SharePoint list.

Is it possible to update a SharePoint List with an InfoPath form querying data?

Comment: Oh, I did forget to mention, that someone told me this isn't possible because the List and Library templates are different, but they also said I couldn't use the email unless I published? But I know the email works for me, so I am questioning their answer and hopefully someone can and will lead me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can in a round-about way update a SharePoint list. The form can only be submitted to a library within SharePoint (at least as far as the submission to SharePoint, you can still submit to databases or emails as well). However, you can promote the properties out as columns within that Library. Then you have 2 options, create a view of the library that does not show the actual form, just the metadata and treat it as a list or use a workflow to create/update entries in that list from the data submitted. Remember that you will have to either use impersonation or allow the same permissions on both the SharePoint LIbrary and list if you use a workflow.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Lori- Thank you, now I have to figure out how to do this. I am new to SharePoint and InfoPath and am learning as I go.

Comment: @Lori- would this be of use? [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/infopath/archive/2007/03/26/submitting-to-a-sharepoint-list.aspx)[link]

Comment: @Lori- what we are wanting to do is have the data pulled from the database and display in an InfoPath list. The user will make modifications (using checkboxes(to update the form)). Then the updated list will be sent to SharePoint.

Comment: @Lori- What we are wanting to do is have data pulled from the database to an InfoPath form. Query the data for active employees, then fwd to managers. The manager will then indicate (using check boxes) who is still employed. If the employee is still here, then their info will update the SharePoint list, if they are no longer here then their data will be forwarded to HR or CIS to update their databases. I don't want to fill out a list in a form and update SharePoint, want to make adjustments to the form from queried data and then update the List. So the previous link, does not needed. :(

Comment: Have you considered using the database as an External Content Type (ECT) and creating an external list with a custom form for it? You have to open SPD and from there you can customize the list form using InfoPath. I haven't tried with multiple items, but I know for many other lists you can select to update multiple items with a single form. Could be something to help you.

Comment: @Lori- the thing with this is, if I am creating an ECT, how are the end users supposed to make updates to the SharePoint List via the InfoPath List, that was created in InfoPath because these two are connected via a database? The final outcome is to reside on a SharePoint List, but is created in InfoPath. I see I can create a list in SharePoint and export it to InfoPth, which this worked the other way too.